# How to create inline images with captions below

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the two lower images in line with each other with captions below each one respectively. Right now I can only make it so they are on top of each other with captions below. I am trying to have each image link to another page. I am having some trouble, so would love if any could help. If you have any questions, feel free to comment below.

```css
/* Imported Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans';
    src: url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

.TopRow{
    font-family: Fira Sans, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
}
.Image1NavBreak{
    line-height:0px;
}

.Image1txt{
    margin-left:10%;
}

.Image1{
    display: block;
    width:80%;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.Image2Nav{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<head>
        <title>TJ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class= TopRow>
        <div>
        <h1>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
            Tj
        </a>
        </h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class = 'Image1Nav'>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="Image1" src="Images/noimg.jpg" alt="noimg.jpg">
        </a>
        <br class= 'Image1NavBreak'>
        </br>
        <div class="Image1txt">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consect
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'Image2Nav'>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="Image2" src="Images/noimg.jpg" alt="noimg.jpg">
        </a>
        <br class= 'Image2NavBreak'>
        </br>
        <div class="Image2txt">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consect
        </p>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <img class="Image3" src="Images/noimg.jpg" alt="noimg.jpg">
            </a>
            <br class= 'Image2NavBreak'>
            </br>
            <div class="Image3txt">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consect
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap Image2 and Image3 inside a `div` and apply `display: flex` on `.Image2Nav` .Refer the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5j0bh739/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Is my solution example please refer this.

```css
/* Imported Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans';
    src: url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

.TopRow{
    font-family: Fira Sans, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
}
.Image1NavBreak{
    line-height:0px;
}

.Image1txt{
    margin-left:10%;
}

.Image1{
    display: block;
    width:80%;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.Image1Nav{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
}
```

```html
<header class= TopRow>
    <div>
        <h1><a href="https://www.google.com">Tj</a></h1>
    </div>
</header>

<div class = 'Image1Nav'>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="Image1" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="noimg.jpg">
    </a>
    <br class= 'Image1NavBreak'>
    </br>
    <div class="Image1txt">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consect
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = 'Image1Nav'>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="Image1" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="noimg.jpg">
    </a>
    <br class= 'Image1NavBreak'>
    </br>
    <div class="Image1txt">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consect
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = 'Image1Nav'>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="Image1" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="noimg.jpg">
    </a>
    <br class= 'Image1NavBreak'>
    </br>
    <div class="Image1txt">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consect
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```